# How to pass Property to ISM through .ini?

Tags: installshield, packaging, basic-msi

I'm building ISM project (Basic MSI) using IsCmdBld.exe. I wanted to pass couple of Properties to ISM file. When I'm executing following command, it's building properly with the passed properties.

```
IsCmdBld.exe -p "<ISM file path>" -z "ProductName=TempProduct" -z "ProductVersion=3.0.0.0" -z "Manufacturer=TempManufacturer" -z "INSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\Temp Product"
```

But I wanted to pass these properties through .ini file. I tried to add these parameters in .ini and passed it to  IsCmdBld.exe with `-i` parameter. Project got build but property didn't get set.

So how we can pass these Property values through .ini file to ISM project while building it using IsCmdBld.exe?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the -i  and -z Property=value on the same command line. Why not call it that way?

It seems odd that Flexera left out the -z replacement when documenting the ini file, http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/helplibrary/IHelpExampleini.htm#buildingtestingdistributing_401868635_1090915

Comment: Currently I'm using -z argument only. But now there are more than 10 properties those I need to pass while building the ISM project. These 10+ properties with -z argument on Command line looking very lengthy.